# how to print selected date month and year into different div tag

Tags: javascript, calendar, bootstrap-datepicker

it is a bootstrap datepicker.js file i want to get date month and day out of that datepicker and print those selected values in different div tags

```
$('.from_date').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '01/01/2012',
    endDate: FromEndDate, 
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(newDate(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.from_date').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '01/01/2012',
    endDate: '01/10/2012', 
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    $('.to_date').html(selected.format());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="from_date"></div>
<div class="to_date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var from_date = $(".from_date").val();
var to_date =$(".to_date").val();

//here we are create an example object input:
<input type="text" id="myInputFrom"/>
<input type="text" id="myInputTo"/>

$("#myInputFrom").val(from_date);
$("#myInputTo").val(to_date);
```

Hope it  helps;)